# Why does my .desktop file execute via double click but not from the menu?

Tags: lubuntu, games, menu, .desktop

I've installed ***FTL: Faster Than Light*** on my girlfriend's Lubuntu machine and **created a .desktop file** for it.  Strangely, the program **won't launch via its menu entry under 'Games'**.

If I navigate to `/home/andi/.local/share/applications/` via ***pcmanfm*** and double click on `FTL Faster Than Light.desktop` **the game launches** without a problem.  I know the menu entry is generated through the .desktop file so **why won't it launch from the menu?**

Here's the .desktop file I created: [FTL Faster Than Light.desktop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1428180/)

Comment: I've also trying placing the .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` with no difference.

Comment: This will execute correctly if you run `cd /home/andi/.local/share/FTL/; ./FTL` I trust?

Comment: @AlexL. Indeed it runs with that command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your response to Alex L.'s comment, it sounds like FTL is looking for various things in your current working directory, so if you navigate using a filebrowser or using cd, it works.  Since the menu doesn't do that, there's something that it can't find.

Try editing the .desktop file so the `Exec` line looks like this instead:

```
sh -c "cd /home/andi/.local/share/FTL/ && ./FTL"
```

That will switch directories first, and should let FTL find everything it needs to start.

Comment: Changed the exec line as you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: In fact that made the game unlaunchable even from the icon in pcmanfm.

Comment: Probably because it is an invalid exec line. Try to wrap it up like this: `sh -c "cd /home/andi/.local/share/FTL/ && ./FTL"`

Comment: I think tried using that exact line before - I know I tried using `sh -c` at least.  I'll give it a go

Comment: @Timo Nope, I must have messed it up before because that worked!  Thanks Timo!

Comment: Edited the original answer to comply with Timo's advice.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following into your text editor:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/andi/.local/share/FTL/
./FTL
exit 0
```

Save it as `FTL-launch` in ~/bin/ and set it as executable. Then change the exec line in your .desktop file to

```
Exec=FTL-launch
```

This is, of course, based on ImaginaryRobots' answer; I've used similar launchers for some old windows games running in wine, where they need to be launched from within their directory.

If you don't have a ~/bin, you'll just have to create one - though then you may need to log out & log in again for it to work.

Comment: I will try as you suggested but I thought setting the `Path=/home/andi/.local/share/FTL/` would take care of that?  On Ubuntu 12.10 the launcher I made worked only after adding that line to the .desktop file.

Comment: I'm sure your answer would have also worked but I prefer to keep it simpler if possible.  The other answer provided a way to fix it within the .desktop file without creating an additional script.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the desktop file? As far as I understand, desktop files need to be installed by doing,

```
sudo desktop-file-install myfile.desktop
```

Where, of course, myfile.desktop should be 'FTL Faster Than Light.desktop' in this case.

You could also try using alacarte (also called Main Menu), in which you can create launchers via a GUI.

Comment: desktop files put in `~/.local/share/applications` will be found by the DE and are no different from those in /usr/...

Comment: @PatricoClark I've created other .desktop files for games and applications in Lubuntu and never ***installed*** them - and they worked from the menu just fine.  I'll give it a shot though and let you know.

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/FTL Faster Than Light.desktop: error: value "'/home/andi/.local/share/FTL/FTL'" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
/usr/share/applications/FTL Faster Than Light.desktop: error: value "'/home/andi/.local/share/FTL/FTL'" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
Error on file "FTL Faster Than Light.desktop": Failed to validate the created desktop file`

Maybe a clue

Comment: Removed single quotes from line `Exec='/home/andi/.local/share/FTL/FTL'` in .desktop file and reran `desktop-file-install FTL\ Faster\ Than\ Light.desktop` which reported no error this ti\me.  Unfortunately it is still not launching from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the `.desktop` file executable. While it's not part of Lubuntu, I know that Nautilus will not run any non executable desktop files. Maybe Lubuntu's menu requires this as well.

Also, I would try removing the spaces from the file name of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: I also have tried making it executable but with no success.  I thought about removing the spaces but seeing other .desktop files with spaces made me hesitate.  I'll give it a go